# What is the keyboard key that you press to insert the comment character?

Tags: xml

What keyboard key do you press to insert the comment character as in this sample line:

```
' This entire line is a comment
```

Comment: What's your keyboard layout or where are you from?

Comment: I'm using a DELL L30U keyboard.

Comment: This character is not the comment symbol for xml, so why do you use this tag?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow and wasn't sure what tag to use. I'm a technical writer and not a programmer, but I need to know how to insert the comment character in a sample code file.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the one with double quotes `"`.

Comment: You're welcome! ¡De nada! Please, accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: You must click on the V icon placed on the left side of the answer. Thanks!